# how to position jquery ui window?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, resize, positioning, jquery-ui-dialog

i tried with position but the dialog shows all the way to the right side and i tweak with numbers but no change in displaying:

```
 $("#div_").dialog("wid").position({ position: [10, 50]});
```

**END UPDATE**

here is my html code that renders below

```
radio button1   sample 
radio button2   sample 
radio button3   sample
```

so what i want is: when the user hover over the "Sample" show the jquery-ui underneath the link

its working for the first link but the second link its showing in middle of the screen, even thoug i have `left, top` assigned, any help?

```
$(document).ready(function () { 

$('#div_').dialog({ 
autoOpen: false, 
}); 

$(".radiobutton1").hover( 
function (){ 
$('#div_').dialog({title: "Iamge Left)"}); 
$('#div_').removeClass("radiobutton1_1 radiobutton2").dialog('open'); 
var target = $(this); 
$("#div_").dialog("wid").position({ 
my: 'left top', 
at: 'center bottom', 
of: target 
}); 
}, 
function (){ 
$('#div_').dialog('close'); 
}); 

$(".radiobutton2").hover( 
function (){ 
$('#div_').dialog({title: "Images Right"}); 
$('#div_').removeClass("radiobutton1_1 radiobutton2").addClass("radiobutton2").dialog('open'); 
 var target = $(this); 

$("#div_").dialog("wid").position({ 
my: 'center top' 
at: 'center bottom', 
of: target 
}); 
}, 
function (){ 
$('#div_').dialog('close'); 
}); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah but for the second you have this :

```
my: 'center top'
```

Would be

```
my: 'left top'
```

Comment: i have tried different setting but if i change the second the first one did not show left

Comment: have you tried with coordinates ? 
Specifies where the dialog should be displayed. Possible values:
1) a single string representing position within viewport: 'center', 'left', 'right', 'top', 'bottom'.
2) an array containing an x,y coordinate pair in pixel offset from left, top corner of viewport (e.g. [350,100])
3) an array containing x,y position string values (e.g. ['right','top'] for top right corner).

Comment: i havent tried but what if; if the user make the window small or maximize window will that coordinates still work or is it fixed? can you show me the example.

Comment: If i remember right the top left is (0,0), so it would work unless they resize to the dialog itself

Comment: okay i have tried `my: 'left top'` but the first one works as expected but the second radiobutton, when i hover over it and it showed top top way out... any sample for what you taking about  positioning?